# How to make textarea with tagging feature like in Youtube

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a textarea that behaves like the tagging box in Youtube. Specifically:

- Allow you to type whatever you want
- When you press space it turns the word you just typed into a tag
- You can remove tags with backspace or by clicking x on tags
- Show suggestions as you type
- You can add tags from outside the textarea as well

Also, what exactly is this method called?

[image: Youtube Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used a javascript library 2 days ago that does excatly this. Check out the [TextExtJs](http://textextjs.com/) library

Comment: Thanks for quick reponse!! This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Great :) Please accept the answer.